# Error attaching debugger with nuclide to Expo local server

Tags: debugging, react-native, expo, nuclide-editor

I am trying to attach the Nuclide debugger to Expo local server (port 19001), but it is showing me the following error :

```
Adapter node: v8.10.0 x64
vscode-chrome-debug-core: 3.17.10
Starting debugger app worker.
******** Unhandled error in debug adapter - Unhandled promise rejection: Error: spawn react-native.cmd ENOENT
        at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Followed by:

```
Could not debug. Invalid Version:
```